# How to replace/exchange/swap content of the clipboard with the selected text

Tags: text, replace, editor, keyboard-shortcuts, clipboard

Despite coding and formatting texts since over 20 years, I'm missing quite often an essential shortcut in my text editors on the following scenario:

```
variable1 = value1
variable2 = value2
```

I want now edit the code by swapping value1 with value2.

```
variable1 = value2
variable2 = value1
```

So what I do since 20 years is

```
select value2
Ctrl+x value2
Ctrl+v before value1
select value1
Ctrl+x value1
Ctrl+v at the old place of value2
```

What I'm missing is a key combination to replace the selected text with the content of the clip board:

```
select value2
Ctrl+x value2
select value1
Ctrl+MAGIC value1  // = swap(clipboard,selected)
Ctrl+v at the old place of value2
```

In Linux I can bypass it using the clipboard and the middle button simultaneously so 2 clip boards.
Who wants to blow my mind?
I guess I'm getting lazy over the years...